# WPF C# How to select between two collection to use in a GridView based on buttons active

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, itemssource

I want to be able to bind two different collection NewItems and OldItems QueryAbleCollection as ItemsSource depending on which radiobutton is active,

let's say we have a button called NewItems and OldItems and each button should change which collection the Itemssource in the GridView should use.

How can I achieve this in the easiest way with XAML and C# ViewModel?

Under is my attempt, but I'm not sure if the smartest thing is to assign SelectedCollection another collection. Can someone correct me if this is a good approach or suggest a better approach? Right now I'm having two buttons which just trigged the isOldItems between true and false.

```
    private bool isOldItems;
    public bool isOldItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isOldItems;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isOldItems= value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("isOldItems");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCollection");
        }
    }


    private QueryableCollectionView _selectedCollection;
    public QueryableCollectionView SelectedCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (isOldItems== true)
                return SelectedCollection= this.OldItemsCollection;
            else
                return SelectedCollection= this.NewItemsCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._selectedCollection!= value)
            {
                this._selectedCollection= value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCollection");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might run into trouble later when modifying the collection, do you ever have to write back to the db? _selectedCollection contains the modified collection, not the Old/New collections.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to modify the collection, and I do write back to the DB.
Do you have any suggestion on how I can solve this?

Comment: I think your best bet is to capture a change event on the radio button and then switch DataContext accordingly. You can write a generic DataContext and fill it with different data. You don't want this because as @dymanoid pointed out, it's bad practice. Viewing only is not so bad I would argue, but if you are going to write as well you will want a clear model that you can easily wrap your head around.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see no obvious huge downside with what you're doing if these are collections of the same type. Broadly speaking anyhow.

That's a reference you're setting so if you set SelectedCollection to NewItemsCollection then it's pointing to NewItemsCollection. Add an item to SelectedCollection and you add to NewItemsCollection  ( or whichever it's set to).

BUT
The if check you have will mean it never sets the backing variable and raises propertychanged from setter.
Objects of the same type are always equal unless you override equals.
Your

```
if (this._selectedCollection!= value)
```

Is not going to check every item in the collection and see if they're different, or the name of the thing you set. What it will do is compare types. These will presumably always be equal.

Remove that if check out the setter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I removed the bool value, and instead I'm doing 

SelectedCollection= this.NewItemsCollection;

when button is clicked. Does it sounds better? :)

I will remove it, but should I remove this too? this._selectedCollection= value;

Comment: There **is** a huge downside of the solution the OP is using. This is called 'property getter with visible and surprising side effects'. This is a really bad practice. Read e.g. [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/82380/310920).

Comment: if (isOldItems== true)
                return SelectedCollection= this.OldItemsCollection;
            else
                return SelectedCollection= this.NewItemsCollection;

In other word, I shouldn't do this over, but rather just return _selectedCollection?